# Attach image to custom menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery, menu, media

i'm trying to attach an image to a wordpress custom menu
for that i made a admin walker and added a link that uses the new wp.media (3.5) uploader with the featuredImage file frame.

everything is ok until i slidedown 2 menu options... then i attach a picture and the picture is set to both menu items like [this](http://cl.ly/image/0j1q2d2J1A17)

i use stopPropagations and still execute for every item displayed
this is the js http://pastebin.com/qBqt3tEN

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution using another plugin idea
i created a gist with it

https://gist.github.com/hugosolar/6077109